# To delete a transparent area of an image in Python

Tags: python, numpy, png

I want to use Python to cut the transparent area of the image file.

Please look at the picture below.

image 1 (original image)

[image]

image 2 (result image)

[image]

The original image has alternating opaque and transparent areas.
I want to transform the image consisting of 1-spaces-2-spaces-3-spaces-4 like the original image into 1-2-3-4.

I tried the following code but failed to get the desired output

```
typfrom PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def trim_transparency(image):
    # Convert image to np.array
    im = np.array(image)

    # Import alpha channels only
    alpha = im[:, :, 3]

    # Found a range of nonzero indexes on each axis
    non_empty_columns = np.where(alpha.max(axis=0)>0)[0]
    non_empty_rows = np.where(alpha.max(axis=1)>0)[0]

    # Found a range of nonzero indexes on each axis
    cropBox = (min(non_empty_rows), max(non_empty_rows), min(non_empty_columns), max(non_empty_columns))

    image_data = Image.fromarray(im).crop(cropBox)

    return image_data

image = Image.open("original_image.png")
new_image = trim_transparency(image)
new_image.save("new_image.png")e here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close - I would use Numpy indexing to gather the rows you want:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image and ensure not palettised, make into Numpy array and select alpha channel
im = Image.open('e0rRU.png').convert('RGBA')
na = np.array(im)
alpha = na[:, :, 3]

# Find opaque rows
non_empty_rows = np.where(alpha.max(axis=1)>0)[0]

# Copy them to new image
opaque = na[non_empty_rows,...]

# Save
Image.fromarray(opaque).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` instead of `max > 0`.

`axis=0` reduces rows, while `axis=1` reduces columns.

Numpy accepts boolean masks as indices directly: there is no need to use `np.where` most of the time.

Cropping in numpy is easier than in PIL. Numpy lets you select or discard all the rows you want, whether or not they're adjacent. PIL functions only seem to operate on contiguous regions.

```
im = np.array(image)
Image.fromarray(im[im[..., -1].any(axis=1)])
```

The index `..., -1` selects the last element of the last dimension. `...` can be used exactly once in an index to indicate `:` for all dimensions that aren't explicitly mentioned.